# why does phosphorus makes 5 bonds with oxygen in P4O10 whereas 3 bonds in P4O6?

Tags: bond

how phosphorus forms 2 types of bonds with oxygen i.e. 5 in $\ce{P4O10}$ and 3 in $\ce{P4O6}$ when only three are needed to complete its octet?

Comment: Did you consider the different oxidation states of phosphorus in both oxides?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! I wouldn't rely too much on octet if I were you, especially when it's about phosphorus. Your question won't make sense if we not rely on octet, which is the case about group 15.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ.  -- too bad there's no such simple reply for Cu(OH)2. I mean, as simple as Chinmay's.

Answer (score 3):

Phosphorus has electronic configuration of ***[Ne]3<sub>S2</sub> 3<sub>P3</sub>*** As it is a 3<sup>rd</sup> period element it also have a vacant ***3<sub>D</sub>*** orbital.

In case of **P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>6</sub>** only the ***3<sub>P3</sub>*** electrons take part. Resulting in formation of 3 bonds with ***O***. But in case of **P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub>** one of the electron of ***3<sub>S</sub>*** is excited to vacant ***3<sub>D</sub>*** orbital. Now **P** has 5 unpaired electron and it can form **5** bonds. Therefore **P** forms 5 in **P<sub>4</sub>O<sub>10</sub>**.

Now, about the octet. Not every compound follow the octet rule. Just to understand **The whole chemistry depends upon STABILITY** i.e lesser energy of molecule. Therefore, if by forming more bonds (and does not obeying Octet rule) the molecule is gaining more stability, it will do so.

Comment: The shape of the 4 Os around P is tetrahedral . Also, according to JD Lee's Concise Inorganic Chemistry, the double bond P=O in P4O10 contains p(pi)-d(pi) backbonding, where a full p-orbital on oxygen overlaps with an empty d-orbital on P ... this seems to point towards an sp3 arrangement with one electron pair from P being "given" to an empty p orbital on O, otherwise how will O attain it's octet ..?